# Changing date value in object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

For example i have a get request which takes some data from mongo db:

```
const getAllContracts = async (req, res) => {
  const contracts = await Contract.find({});
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ contracts, count: contracts.length });
};
```

As response it sends:

```
{
    "contracts": [
        {
            "_id": "637cbd3279de1dd12dd7d2f9",
            "tenant": "Nazar",
            "manager": "Misha",
            "object": "Автовокзал",
            "price": 99,
            "area": 335,
            "status": "Активний",
            "activeFrom": "2022-11-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "activeUntil": "2022-11-18T00:00:00.000Z",
            "createdBy": "6372c4bc0c02f9ccf3363fe0",
            "contractManualId": "321a",
            "contractReason": "IDK",
            "contractComment": "Vasya",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-22T12:14:42.248Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-22T12:14:42.248Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "637cbd4d79de1dd12dd7d2fc",
            "tenant": "Nazar1111",
            "manager": "Misha",
            "object": "Автовокзал",
            "price": 99,
            "area": 335,
            "status": "Активний",
            "activeFrom": "2022-11-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "activeUntil": "2022-11-18T00:00:00.000Z",
            "createdBy": "6372c4bc0c02f9ccf3363fe0",
            "contractManualId": "321a",
            "contractReason": "IDK",
            "contractComment": "Vasya",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-22T12:15:09.755Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-22T12:15:09.755Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "count": 2
}
```

I would like to change response date formats in activeFrom and activeUntil to dd-mm-yyyy but idk how to do that. For example 2022-11-16T00:00:00.000Z i want to change to 16.11.2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:
Loop over contracts and modify the properties

```js
contracts.map((contract) => {
  const activeFromDate = new Date(contract.activeFrom);
  contract.activeFrom = formatDate(activeFromDate);

  const activeUntilDate = new Date(contract.activeUntil);
  contract.activeUntil = formatDate(activeUntilDate);
  return contract;
});
```

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  // the +1 is because getMonth is zero-based.
  return `${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth() + 1}.${date.getFullYear()}`
}
```

But couple of thoughts:
1.) If you're passing this to UI code it would be "cleaner" for the UI to do this formatting.
2.) IF you *have to* do this on the backend return both the formatted and raw data rather than the inplace update like above.
So same structure but instead of assigning to `contract.activeFrom` you should assign the resultant to `contract.formattedActiveFrom` and return both properties to the UI. That way if they need to do any additional tinkering with the date they have it available in a format that's easy to use.